# Set alignment for one member in the stackView

Tags: swift, stackview

I have a stack view that contains three item, 2 labels (one of them in the left side and another one in the right side), and one view as a separator in the middle. 
How the configuration of the stackView should look like that the separator has a left alignment.
I mean the separator should stay closer to the left item than the right one.

your help will be appreciated.

Comment: let me know if my answer resolve your problem sir

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Give separator a fix width and add another empty `UIView()` in the stack after separator which will cover the remaining space. This way your right label stay on right and left label with separator aligns left **Cheers**